# CSS: min-height works only like height

Tags: html, css

I have a repeating background-image on my body tag. It works fine, as long as the content is shorter than the browser window.

Code:

```
html {
height:100%;
}

body {
background-image:url('images/pattern.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
min-height:100%;
}
```

When the content is too long for the window and I have to scroll down, the pattern is not til the bottom of the website.

There is also my live example: http://syrien.wernersbacher.de/

Question: I want to have the background pattern, even if the content is big. How to fix it?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Please add your question, so we have something to advice on :-)

Comment: @wernersbacher, I have updated css, try that

Comment: @RajivRanjan take a look on koningdavid's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clearing your floats, try adding the following CSS to make the "#main" container wrap till the full height:

```
#main:after {
    content: "";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

If you add this, your "#main" will wrap the inner elements, and make the html wrap the entire page

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floating point in content as you are using `float:right;`

After the `<div id="content"></div>` add a div having `clear:both;`

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the floating `div#content`. Floating elements don't extend their parent elements. A simple solution is to add `overflow:auto` to `div#main`. You don't need `(min-)height` on your `body` element.